# May you please reconsider the code-formatting "help" box?

Tags: discussion

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't proper code-formatting another issue in the realm of communication?

An improperly formatted code block does not communicate well to the reader. The issue is mainly about consistency. If you indent by 2 spaces everywhere, and it is readable then it is readable

But when you force the user to use a *specific* code-formatting convention, how is this useful??

[image]

This error message is opaque. "Appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."  Uhh, Ok Watson? I thought this was a *user-driven* community. You know, trust and all that.

Please let me submit a question normally like before. I've tried at least 20 times to submit a post, to no avail. These obstacle-courses-to-question-submission are too much.

Comment: The error message _could_ be clearer though, admittedly.

Comment: @JonasCz, agreed can we fix that part at least please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe are missing the point. 4 spaces are for the markdown engine to recognise it is code.

You are free to only indent by 2 spaces, after you indented it by 4 spaces to recognise it as code.

Take a look at the [markdown-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

---

**Examples:**

2 Spaces like this:

```
  public void() {
      Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld")
  }
```

Looks like this:

public void() {
  Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld")
}

---

4 Spaces like this:

```
    public void() {
        Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld")
    }
```

Looks so:

```
public void() {
    Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld")
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> If you indent by 2 spaces everywhere, and it is readable then it is readable
>
> But when you force the user to use a specific code-formatting convention, how is this useful??

This isn't about StackOverflow imposing coding conventions on your code.

This is about **Markdown** formatting. If you want code to render **as code**, meaning wrapped in `<code>` tags, you need to apply a **leading** indent of four spaces to each line.

Comment: The wording of that error message can be better IMHO. I can understand why the OP is confused. Perhaps something like "Your post appears to contain code which isn't properly marked as being code. To make sure it's rendered correctly please indent all code by four spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut." would be better...

Comment: @Coffee Your proposed wording seems more problematic to me than the original. I would be more likely to interpret "isn't formatted correctly" as referring to stylistic/convention preferences than I would "is not properly formatted as code." The "as code" part is critical. It is telling you that the system does not interpret it as being code. Of course, all of this should be patently obvious from the preview below the input box. How is it that you missed that?

Comment: [Bikeshed painting time!](http://bikeshed.com/), but yeah, I agree with CodyGray; I avoided "formatting" for exactly that reason. It's ambiguous.

Comment: Granted, good points above. Then I fully support @carpetsmoker with the modest above change. Bikeshed is relevant but, hey- what can you do

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Rather than "please indent all code by four spaces" I would suggest "please indent each line of code with a leading 4 spaces".